# Deploying Static Content on M2 doesn't work

Tags: magento-2.1, static-content

I am trying to deploy static content on my production site but I am receiving the error in the screenshot. Why is this occurring?

[image]

Comment: Please update your last changes to code/module.

Comment: I haven't made any changes. I have noticed all php bin/magento commands are showing errors

Comment: Could be related to folder rights. Give a try to give full control to the folders var and pub like sudo chmod -R 777 var pub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate similar behaviour with changing database credentials to **wrong ones**.

[image]

By the error seems that `bin/magento` executable thinks that the app is not installed and I would start with checking if configs in app/etc folder are correct, all files present and `env.php` values are correct.